# Paginator return to the same page

Tags: wordpress

When I click on a number of my paginator, the URL changes, but return to the index page, not to page 2, 3... What is wrong? This is the code that I'm currently using

**category.php**

```
<?php                   

$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;

$args = array(
    'cat' => get_query_var('cat'),
        'posts_per_page' => 3,
        'paged'=>$paged
);

$custom_query = new WP_Query( $args );

if ($custom_query ->have_posts()): while($custom_query ->have_posts()): $custom_query ->the_post(); ?>

...

<?php endwhile; ?>

    <?php kriesi_pagination($custom_query->max_num_pages); ?>

<?php endif; ?>
```

**functions.php**

```
function kriesi_pagination($pages = '', $range = 2)
{  
     $showitems = ($range * 2)+1;  

     global $paged;
     if(empty($paged)) $paged = 1;

     if($pages == '')
     {
         global $wp_query;
         $pages = $wp_query->max_num_pages;

         if(!$pages)
         {
             $pages = 1;
         }
     }   

     if(1 != $pages)
     {
         echo "<div class='pagination'>";
         if($paged > 2 && $paged > $range+1 && $showitems < $pages) echo "<a href='".get_pagenum_link(1)."'>&laquo;</a>";
         if($paged > 1 && $showitems < $pages) echo "<a href='".get_pagenum_link($paged - 1)."'>&lsaquo;</a>";

         for ($i=1; $i <= $pages; $i++)
         {
             if (1 != $pages &&( !($i >= $paged+$range+1 || $i <= $paged-$range-1) || $pages <= $showitems ))
             {
                 echo ($paged == $i)? "<span class='current'>".$i."</span>":"<a href='".get_pagenum_link($i)."' class='inactive' >".$i."</a>";
             }
         }

         if ($paged < $pages && $showitems < $pages) echo "<a href='".get_pagenum_link($paged + 1)."'>&rsaquo;</a>";  
         if ($paged < $pages-1 &&  $paged+$range-1 < $pages && $showitems < $pages) echo "<a href='".get_pagenum_link($pages)."'>&raquo;</a>";
         echo "</div>\n";
     }
}
```

I suspect that could be something related with `$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;,` but I tried changing that without success.

The returned url is like `"?cat=4&paged=4"`